# Reusable components structure (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

I want to seek advice regarding reusable components structure in react-native. I wanted to make them lean and adaptive. What I thought was to have generic components as wrappers and then have specific  components using those wrappers. e.g. For products carousel I pass products data to `Carousel component`  (just a FlatList) that renders `Card component` multiple times that has products details and product related icons. But what If I want to have categories or anything else inside card?
What I thought is to make card content passed as props

```
<Carousel>
 {.... // ProductContent}
</Carousel>

<Carousel>
 {.... // CategoriesContent}
</Carousel>
```

But it seems like I am over complicating things as I'll pass data to carousel, then carousel will pass it to card then card will pass it back to my content and carousel is mere a Flatlist and card is mere a TouchableOpacity. And also it will not look clean as I will have to define the content wherever I am using the Carousel. Why not just create two separate carousel components

```
<ProductCarousel />
<CategoriesCarousel />
```

Similarly I have a `<PopUpModal />` component. which I am using for showing product details. Should I pass product content as children to keep content generic or just create `<ProductDetailModal />` as a component and  create more modals if required

So the point is whether to have specific bits and pieces of the app as components so that connecting them will complete the puzzle or to have generic customizable wrappers like components. Or something in between

Comment: The beauty of react is that you can choose how to compose these. Most people end up somewhere in between the two extremes. The goal is to simplify, not eliminate code-duplication. Check out this great post/talk from Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/the-wet-codebase/

Comment: With a complex structure of components by my experience bug fixing and changes are difficult. I try to make components out of real-life objects. If an app needs a specific card I make this card, if it needs another one that logically fits, I try to re-use, otherwise not. For specific styles and colors you can still make global Stylesheets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend atomic design.

Its hard to explain it here, so Ill leave a link.

https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/

The key point is to break(modularize) everything into tiny, replacable & reusable bits, and actually reusing and replacing them.

Another important, yet often neglected point is that separating smart and dumb components.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

This is surely neglected and also seems cumbersome to aplly, but will simplify the codebase by detaching view related logic to data(api) related logic.

So those are the two rules I try to stick to.

P.S. Just as im_baby has pointed out in the comments, there is no answer, and we all compromise at some point. So try to be long sighted and practical, dont be dogmastic to rules, neither be short sighted and mess up the overall code quality and structure for immediate comfort

Answer (score -1):

You will make a component like this giving the parent component all the liberty to change it through props.

```
render() {
    const { all the props that you want to give your component} = this.props;
    return (
      <Carousel>
        {this.props.childern} // like this you can design your one carosal and cahnge the data/view in the carosal.
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
```

Then in your parent component you need to import this component like this:

import CarouselComponent from '../CarouselComponent'; //path to your component

```
<Carousel>
  <View>
    //any view you want to be rendered in the modal
  </View>
</Carousel>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kulsoom but this not what I asked. I have already mentioned it as first approach in the question. I asked for comparison among diff approaches acc. to experience